# Put files in a folder dynamically in c++

Tags: c++, linux

Lets say I have a txt file and in the txt file it is written: "doc1.doc, doc2.doc, doc3.doc".. etc.
In my code, I read this txt file and find the documents "doc1.doc, doc2.doc..".

I want to put these doc files in a folder while I am reading the txt file, using c++. Is it possible?

Assume I have a folder already, no need to create a new folder. Only concern is putting the files into the folder.

Edit: I am using linux.

Comment: Did you read a good book on Linux or Posix programming, like http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ ?

Comment: It might be possible, but it's not clear what is it you're wanting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't provide enough information to get a complete answer. C++ as a language doesn't really have functions to work with folders, or files in that sense. That's because C++ is platform-agnostic which means that you can compile C++ code to run on Windows, MacOS, iOS, Android, Linux any many other devices that don't even have a file system.

Of course, in your case you are probably referring to either Windows or Linux. And if that's the case then, depending on which one it is, you can use file-system functions to copy or move files in the file-system.

For Windows, the Win32 API has the [CopyFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and CopyFileEx function to copy files and the [MoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365239%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and MoveFileEx functions to move or rename files.

For Linux, you might use the [sendfile](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile) API function to copy a file using the kernel.

I should point out that it is possible to write some platform agnostic code in C/C++ to copy the contents of a file to another file using the open/read/write functions(i.e. open the source file in read mode, open the target file in write mode, and then keep reading from the source and writing to the target until the end of source file is reached) but other file-system functions are more difficult, if not impossible to reproduce without platform-specific libraries.

**UPDATE**

Since you specified that you want to do it in linux, here's how you might use the sendfile function:

```
int inputFileDesc;
int outputFileDesc;
struct stat statBuffer;
off_t offset = 0;

// open the source file, and get a file descriptor to identify it later (for closing and sendfile fn)
inputFileDesc = open ("path_to_source_file", O_RDONLY);

// this function will fill the statBuffer struct with info about the file, including the size in bytes
fstat (inputFileDesc, &statBuffer);

// open the destination file and get a descriptor to identify it later (for closing and writing to it)
outputFileDesc = open ("path_to_destination_file", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, statBuffer.st_mode);

// this is the API function that actually copies file data from source to dest;
//   it takes as params the descriptors of the input and output files and an offset and length for the amount of data to copy over
sendfile (outputFileDesc, inputFileDesc, &offset, statBuffer.st_size);

close (outputFileDesc);    // closes the output file (identified by descriptor) 
close (inputFileDesc);     // closes the input file (identified by descriptor)
```

Comment: How can I make system calls? Like: system("cp (doc1.doc) newfolder"); What can I write instead of doc1.doc?

Comment: @gozdebaris what do you ''want'' to write?

Comment: The solution suggests using system functions. I learned that system calls are made like this: system("cp doc1.doc newfolder"). Now the problem is I can not write this line to my code. I am reading "doc1.doc" from the txt file..

Comment: well, assuming that you read the name of the file from the text file, you would want to use that in place of the "path_to_source_file" and the path+file name of the destination file in the other place..

Comment: thanks, but the code seems really hard for me, can you write a few comments? I did not unsderstand what is going on

Comment: No, the `system(3)` library function is not a syscall. TYpe `man 2 intro` to get an introduction to syscalls

Comment: @gozdebaris, I can add some comments for you but I'm afraid that if you don't understand this simple example you need to take a step back and maybe learn the basics. You should start asking more direct questions, until it starts making sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Giomm, a part of glibmm which is a C++ binding for Glib. Take a look, very intuitive (more than low-level system/posix C functions):

http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1File.html#details

This one may be useful for directory iteration:

[http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGlib_1_1Dir.html](http://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/2.34/classGlib_1_1Dir.html)

It's also portable! It will work everywhere Glib works. Windows, Linux, MacOS... you won't be limited to linux. It does mean you depend on Glim and glibmm, but Glib is very commonly used by GNU/Linux software, and any GUI application which uses GTK or any binding of it, loads Glib anyway so very likely, depending on your case though, that this solution doesn't really add an extra dependency.

Also, a big advantage, especially if using Linux, is that you can go to source code of free software and see what the codes does there. For example, you can go to Gnome's git repositories, available at [git.gnome.org](http://git.gnome.org), then go to a project that works with documents, e.g. the text editor [gedit](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gedit), and find out how it saves documents to the files. Or even better, check a project written in C++ (gedit is written in C), such as Glom or Inkscape or Gnote, and see what they do.